# Mysterious login attempts to windows server

Tags: security, windows

I have a Windows 2008R2 server that is reporting failed login attempts from a number of workstations on our network.  Some event log details:

Event ID 4625, Status: 0xc000006d, Sub Status: 0xc0000064
Security ID: NULL SID, Account Name: joedoe, Account Domain: Acme
Workstation Name: WINXP1, Source Network Address: 192.168.1.23, Source Port: 1904
Logon Process: NtLmSsp, Authentication Package: NTLM, Logon Type: 3 (network)

I believe this is coming from some netbios service or similar (maybe the file explorer), keeping an inventory of its network neighborhood and also trying to authenticate.

Is there a way to turn this off without having to turn off file sharing all together?  In other words, clients authenticating against file servers that they use is of course no problem, but I want to eliminate clients trying to authenticate to servers that they are not using and have no business with.  The above example is only one of thousands of log alerts for similar failed network authentications.

What can I do to clean this up / handle this?

Comment: Clients don't randomly access network resources. Clients also don't normally maintain the network browse list. Even if they did (and they can in certain scenarios) they don't authenticate or attempt to log on to any other host to build said list.

Comment: I agree with @joeqwerty, clients do not randomly access network resources. Are you sure that these specific workstations are virus free? Do you recognize the usernames it is trying to authenticate with or are they generic?

Comment: What anti-virus and anti-malware software are you using? Maybe it's time to get something better and scan every machine properly. Your symptoms suggest your systems have been compromised.

Comment: We are using ESET NOD32 and they are updated with the latest signatures.  The authentication attempt happen as the user logs in, with the same login name as the user.  I have checked the machines and cannot find any signs of malware, viruses or other uninvited stuff.

Comment: What services is the server providing? File services? Print services? Does the user have a drive letter mapped to a share on the server?

Comment: The server is only for EDI (with SQL Server running as well).  No file or printer shares.

Comment: I have managed to reproduce this "authentication failure" now.  All you have to do is to go to "My Network Places" on one of the XP machines in question, and it will try to authenticate to this server.  This seems to confirm that it is no malware involved here. I guess the only way to prevent that is to create a Group Policy to disable My Network Places (or Computers Near Me, etc.).   Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you checked other servers for similar events? Other workstations on the same network? What is the destination port?

Answer (score 0):

Given the solution you found, I suggest removing items from the Network Places folder. One easy way to do this is via batch during login:

```
RD /S /Q "c:\Documents and Settings\%1\NetHood\" >nul
MD "C:\Documents and Settings\%1\NetHood\"
```